# Any solution to convert HTML to BBcode

Tags: php, html, bbcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert HTML to BBCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308734/how-to-convert-html-to-bbcode)

Is there any php class or library to convert HTML to BB Code?
I looked in Package Information: HTML_BBCodeParser, but this is doing vast vice versa.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4308734/569659