# PHP BBcode parsing

Tags: php, parsing, bbcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert HTML to BBCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308734/how-to-convert-html-to-bbcode)

how can i parse

```
<tag attr="z">
<tag attr="y">
<tag attr="x"></tag>
</tag>
</tag>
```

to

```
<tag attr="z">
[tag=y]
<tag attr="x"></tag>
[/tag]
</tag>
```

Without using extensions ...

Comment: You're trying to transform HTML back into BB tags. The typical dumb SO comments ala "you can't parse html with regex" is relevant here (albeit wrong). It's just awfully difficult. Matching the right closing `</span>` is no small feat. So use a DOM frontend or the mentioned XSLT approach.

Comment: I cant use extensions .. =\ and i cant use frontend ..

Comment: DOMDocument is the built-in traversal frontend to the libxml2 parser. The XSLT functions are often not, but a xslt processor is often available through the commandline. If you don't like either simple option, you're either in for a lot of workaround coding, or plain [googling](http://www.google.de/search?client=opera&rls=de&q=convert+html+back+to+bbcode).

Comment: I updated my question and explained it better ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP can handle BBCode itself. **[See Here](http://il.php.net/bbcode)**

Comment: I updaded my question and explained it better ..