# PHP How to parse html tags in textarea like phpBB does

Tags: php, html-parsing, xss, phpbb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert HTML to BBCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308734/how-to-convert-html-to-bbcode)

Im building community website where users are allowed to post topics.
Of course i should be aware of many problems that can happen when some "smart"
user tries to "post" something that is not meant to be what it should be.
Basicly im trying to protect myself from XSS.
In my textarea field of course i should filter html tags, and not allow
**script or iframe tags**.
 Nice way to change html tags with custom tags, like phpBB does
for example : 
**[b] bold [/b]** 
**[code] snippet here [/code]** 
**[list] unordered list [/list]**
How can i do this in php, or simply how can i catch those tags as string in php an perform
rendering when reading the text.

Comment: you are taking about BBcode: http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Comment: *Don't* do this yourself.  There are *lots* of libraries that do this, like [NBBC](http://nbbc.sourceforge.net/) and [HTML_BBCodeParser2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser2).

Comment: I think you have that one in the wrong direction, Dagon.  The user is trying to go *from* BBCode *to* HTML.

Comment: @Charles dont u think they are a bit outdated as i use html5 on my project and NBBC converts to xhtml 1 strict.

Comment: @Alian.Vesuf, [HTML5 is backwards compatible with XHTML syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#syntax), and there is an XML serialization in addition to the HTML serialization.  Honestly, there's nothing in XHTML that is objectionable in HTML5 other than self-closing tags (`<br>` vs `<br />`).

Comment: @Charles nBBC does the job. Thanks man :) ! Helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel, take a look at [Bulletin Board Code](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) on PHP.net.

Comment: The BBCode extension is *not* built-in.  It's an optional PECL module.

Comment: Yeah, sure! I haven't said that is built-in.